# Why are the results identical even though the model training has not yet converged?

Tags: python, deep-learning

What really perplexes me is that the results for different test examples on the same test set are completely identical (up to four decimal places). Even after changing the dataset, the pattern remains the same; only the values differ.

code:

```py
class Con(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=1):
        super(Con, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(201856, 128, 5)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(128, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.unsqueeze(1)  
        out = self.layer1(x)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)  
        out = out.unsqueeze(0) 
        out, hid = self.lstm(out)
        out = out.squeeze(0) 
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out
```

test function：

```py
total_loss = 0.0
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    
    for inputs, labels in test_loader:
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
        labels = Variable(labels.float())
        #print(labels)
        inputs = Variable(torch.tensor(inputs).float())
        outputs = model(inputs)
        print(outputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels.unsqueeze(1).float())
        total_loss += loss.item()
    
    avg_loss = total_loss / len(test_loader)
    print(f"Average Loss on test set: {avg_loss:.4f}")
```

I have tried changing the activation function and adjusting the learning rate, but it has not made any difference.